# Warning: move_uploaded_file( C: \ xampp \ htdocs\photo_gallery\public\images\powder.jpg): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\

Tags: php

```
<?php
// If it's going to need the database, then it's 
// probably smart to require it before we start.
require_once('database.php');

class Photograph extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $table_name="photographs";
    protected static $db_fields=array('id', 'filename', 'type', 'size', 'caption');
    public $id;
    public $filename;
    public $type;
    public $size;

public $caption;

    private $temp_path;
  protected $upload_dir="images";
  public $errors=array();

  protected $upload_errors = array(
        // http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
        UPLOAD_ERR_OK               => "No errors.",
        UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => "Larger than upload_max_filesize.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL        => "Partial upload.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE        => "No file.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "No temporary directory.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Can't write to disk.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => "File upload stopped by extension."
    );

    // Pass in $_FILE(['uploaded_file']) as an argument
  public function attach_file($file) {
        // Perform error checking on the form parameters
        if(!$file || empty($file) || !is_array($file)) {
          // error: nothing uploaded or wrong argument usage
          $this->errors[] = "No file was uploaded.";
          return false;
        } elseif($file['error'] != 0) {
          // error: report what PHP says went wrong
          $this->errors[] = $this->upload_errors[$file['error']];
          return false;
        } else {
            // Set object attributes to the form parameters.
          $this->temp_path  = $file['tmp_name'];
          $this->filename   = basename($file['name']);
          $this->type       = $file['type'];
          $this->size       = $file['size'];
            // Don't worry about saving anything to the database yet.
            return true;

        }
    }

    public function save() {
        // A new record won't have an id yet.
        if(isset($this->id)) {
            // Really just to update the caption
            $this->update();
        } else {
            // Make sure there are no errors

            // Can't save if there are pre-existing errors
          if(!empty($this->errors)) { return false; }

            // Make sure the caption is not too long for the DB
          if(strlen($this->caption) > 255) {
                $this->errors[] = "The caption can only be 255 characters long.";
                return false;
            }

          // Can't save without filename and temp location
          if(empty($this->filename) || empty($this->temp_path)) {
            $this->errors[] = "The file location was not available.";
            return false;
          }

            // Determine the target_path
          $target_path = SITE_ROOT .DS. 'public' .DS. $this->upload_dir .DS. $this->filename;

          // Make sure a file doesn't already exist in the target location
          if(file_exists($target_path)) {
            $this->errors[] = "The file {$this->filename} already exists.";
            return false;
          }

            // Attempt to move the file 
             if(move_uploaded_file($this->temp_path, $target_path)){
            // Success
                // Save a corresponding entry to the database
                if($this->create()) {
                    // We are done with temp_path, the file isn't there anymore
                    unset($this->temp_path);
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                // File was not moved.
            $this->errors[] = "The file upload failed, possibly due to incorrect permissions on the upload folder.";
            return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public function destroy() {
        // First remove the database entry
        if($this->delete()) {
            // then remove the file
          // Note that even though the database entry is gone, this object 
            // is still around (which lets us use $this->image_path()).
            $target_path = SITE_ROOT.DS.'public'.DS.$this->image_path();
            return unlink($target_path) ? true : false;
        } else {
            // database delete failed
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function image_path() {
      return $this->upload_dir.DS.$this->filename;
    }

    public function size_as_text() {
        if($this->size < 1024) {
            return "{$this->size} bytes";
        } elseif($this->size < 1048576) {
            $size_kb = round($this->size/1024);
            return "{$size_kb} KB";
        } else {
            $size_mb = round($this->size/1048576, 1);
            return "{$size_mb} MB";
        }
    }

    public function comments() {
        return Comment::find_comments_on($this->id);
    }


    // Common Database Methods
    public static function find_all() {
        return self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name);
  }

  public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
      global $database;
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name." WHERE id=".$database->escape_value($id)." LIMIT 1");
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
  }

  public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
      $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
    }
    return $object_array;
  }

    public static function count_all() {
      global $database;
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".self::$table_name;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
      $row = $database->fetch_array($result_set);
    return array_shift($row);
    }

    private static function instantiate($record) {
        // Could check that $record exists and is an array
    $object = new self;
        // Simple, long-form approach:
        // $object->id              = $record['id'];
        // $object->username    = $record['username'];
        // $object->password    = $record['password'];
        // $object->first_name = $record['first_name'];
        // $object->last_name   = $record['last_name'];

        // More dynamic, short-form approach:
        foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
          if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
          }
        }
        return $object;
    }

    private function has_attribute($attribute) {
      // We don't care about the value, we just want to know if the key exists
      // Will return true or false
      return array_key_exists($attribute, $this->attributes());
    }

    protected function attributes() { 
        // return an array of attribute names and their values
      $attributes = array();
      foreach(self::$db_fields as $field) {
        if(property_exists($this, $field)) {
          $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
        }
      }
      return $attributes;
    }

    protected function sanitized_attributes() {
      global $database;
      $clean_attributes = array();
      // sanitize the values before submitting
      // Note: does not alter the actual value of each attribute
      foreach($this->attributes() as $key => $value){
        $clean_attributes[$key] = $database->escape_value($value);
      }
      return $clean_attributes;
    }

    // replaced with a custom save()
    // public function save() {
    //   // A new record won't have an id yet.
    //   return isset($this->id) ? $this->update() : $this->create();
    // }

    public function create() {
        global $database;
        // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
        // - INSERT INTO table (key, key) VALUES ('value', 'value')
        // - single-quotes around all values
        // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
        $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
      $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
        $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
      $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
        $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
        $sql .= "')";
      if($database->query($sql)) {
        $this->id = $database->insert_id();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    public function update() {
      global $database;
        // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
        // - UPDATE table SET key='value', key='value' WHERE condition
        // - single-quotes around all values
        // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
        $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
        $attribute_pairs = array();
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
          $attribute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
        $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
        $sql .= " WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
      $database->query($sql);
      return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
    }

    public function delete() {
        global $database;
        // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
        // - DELETE FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1
        // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
        // - use LIMIT 1
      $sql = "DELETE FROM ".self::$table_name;
      $sql .= " WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
      $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
      $database->query($sql);
      return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;

        // NB: After deleting, the instance of User still 
        // exists, even though the database entry does not.
        // This can be useful, as in:
        //   echo $user->first_name . " was deleted";
        // but, for example, we can't call $user->update() 
        // after calling $user->delete().
    }

}

?>
```

I am getting some warnings on `move_upload_file`. I tried to diagnose the problem but I failed. Here is the error i am getting.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file( C: \ xampp \
>   htdocs\photo_gallery\public\images\powder.jpg): failed to open stream:
>   Invalid argument in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\photograph.php on line 88
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\php46A4.tmp' to ' C: \ xampp \
>   htdocs\photo_gallery\public\images\powder.jpg' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\photograph.php on line 88

Comment: Long time since I used PHP, but still, your path (god I can't quote it correctly) seems too _spacious_ to me.

Comment: Your path for file uploading is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be in `SITE_ROOT` variable, it should have no spaces on it

As it seems, SITE_ROOT has this value

```
C: \ xampp \ htdocs\photo_gallery
```

but it should have this

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery
```

If you show us the code where you set SITE_ROOT, we could help you fix it

**EDIT** (as per your comment on this question)

Your error is in this line you put on the comment of this question

```
define('SITE_ROOT', " c:\ xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery" );
```

It should have no spaces, like this

```
define('SITE_ROOT', "c:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery" );
```

Comment: here is where is my site root defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 
 define('SITE_ROOT', " c:\ xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery" );
    
  
define("LIBRARY_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/library'));
     but now i am getting error says file location was not found.

Comment: now i am getting the same error when i correct the site root.:Warning: move_uploaded_file(c: mpp\htdocs\photo_gallery\public\images\powder.jpg): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\photograph.php on line 89

Comment: make sure that the path exists `C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\`

Comment: i put the images in public/image folder..i dont know why it says file location is not available

Comment: how to make temp location.is what this codes are saying.but now are i am confuse : // Can't save without filename and temp location
    if(empty($this->filename) || empty($temp_path)) {
      $this->errors[] = "The file location was not available.";
      return false;
    }